# Java Regex matching whole word containing special characters

Tags: java, regex, string, escaping, match

I'am trying to match certain keywords in a text of string. The keywords can contain any combination of special characters and must be a whole word (without space).

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String words[] = {"Hello", "World", "£999.00", "*&332", "$30,00", "$1230.30",
                    "Apple^*$Banana&$Pears!$", "90.09%"};

    String text = "Hello world World £99900 £999.00 Apple^*$Banana&$Pears!$"
                  + " $30,00 *&332 $1230.30 90.09%";

    StringBuilder regex = new StringBuilder();
    regex.append("(");

    for(String item : word)
        regex.append("(?:^|\\s)").append(item).append("(?:$|\\s)").append("|");

    regex.deleteCharAt(buildRegex.length() - 1);
    regex.append(")");

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex.toString());

    Matcher match = pattern.matcher(text);

    while (match.find())
        System.out.println(match.group());
}
```

The results I get is:

**Hello

World

£999.00

&332

90.09%**

Not all of the words match. I've tried different solution posted here and searching and non could match all the words in my example.

How can I match keywords containing any combination of special characters?

Comment: Define "keywords containing any combination of special characters". Is a "A%%%%" or "%%%%%A" or "%%%%" such word?

Comment: Yeah the above is correct, basically a keywords can contain any combination of characters except space. So it must be a whole keyword.  
 Correct: ££hello  
 Correct: hello££  
 Incorrect: ££hello hello££

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `lookaround` based regex should work:

```
for(String item : words)
   regex.append("(?<=^|\\s)").append(Pattern.quote(item)).append("(?=\\s|$)").append("|");
```

Main difference is:

- Use of lookarounds to avoid matching spaces. When 2 consecutive matches are to be found this creates problem in your regex since space has already been consumed.
- Use of `Pattern.quote` to take care of special characters

This gets output:

```
Hello
World
£999.00
Apple^*$Banana&$Pears!$
$30,00
*&332
$1230.30
90.09%
```

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked. Use of `Lookarounds` is very important sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Pattern.quote()`. What is more, you need to use a lookbehind and a lookahead:

```
for(String item : word)
    regex.append("(?<=^|\\s)")
        .append(Pattern.quote(item)) // HERE
        .append("(?=$|\\s)").append("|");
```

Basically, what this method does is prepend `\Q` and append `\E` to the string. See the javadoc for `Pattern`.

Comment: I also tried that but again only some keyword match. The word which match using your solution is:
Hello 
World
£999.00
$30,00
$1230.30